# When I install fvm and run `fvm flutter doctor` I get an error `! Warning: `flutter` on your path resolves` error

Tags: flutter, dart, fvm

If you install fvm and run `fvm flutter doctor

```
    ! Warning: `flutter` on your path resolves to /Users/user/development/flutter/bin/flutter, which is not inside your current Flutter SDK checkout at /Users/user/fvm/versions/3.16.4. Consider adding /Users/user/fvm/versions/3.16.4/bin to the front of your path.
    ! Warning: `dart` on your path resolves to /Users/user/development/flutter/bin/dart, which is not inside your current Flutter SDK checkout at /Users/user/fvm/versions/3.16.4. Consider adding /Users/user/fvm/versions/3.16.4/bin to the front of your path.
```

When I look online, it says to uninstall dart,

```
user@com ~ % brew uninstall dart
Error: No such keg: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/dart
```

I am getting the error "I have a problem.
How can I get rid of these errors?

I would appreciate your help to solve this issue.

Comment: As a former user of FVM, I'm happy to have replaced it entirely with https://puro.dev., which covers the same basic needs in a far more efficient and user-friendly way.  Also, can you clarify how you installed dart?  Generally people install dart as part of flutter.

Comment: I see that there is a `puro.dev`. Thank you for telling me about it.
It has been so long since I installed dart that I don't remember how I did it, but I think I installed it according to the official instructions.